# session variable or cookies

Tags: php, javascript

I have got a web page `welcome.php`, user enters some information on `welcome.php` page and submits the data, it posts the user data to `registration.php` page through `$_POST['data']`. This is the basic concept.

But if user opens my `registration.php` through some search engine or any other means. Can i redirect him to the welcome page. The answer is `Yes` I know its possible.

But the confusion is whether to set a `session variable` in php or use `cookies` (but if user disables cookies?) or is there any other simple way to do it?

**My Approach**

Create a session variable in php and set its value. Now when user opens the `registration.php` check if variable `isset()` and if its not set redirect him to `welcome.php`

I dont know if its a  good idea of doing it. I dont know if there are  some more easy ways to do it.Kindly let me know the best way of doing it.

What I was thinking is to reduce work done by server as low as possible. Thanks. also let me know what are `cookies` and `sessions` and when do we need them and what are their uniqueness.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Referer` HTTP header?

Comment: @MaxArt it can be disabled like the cookies

Comment: @niko could you clarify your intention: are you trying to check whether the user has never been to the site before and is coming from a search engine, or are you trying to lock down content or something? To me it seems like you just want to show a welcome page if the user has never been to the site, but I may have understood you wrong.

Comment: @byf-ferdy So what? If the header is null, then redirect to the welcome page.

Comment: @MaxArt he could use cookies then aswell. The benefit from using cookies would be that the HTTP-Referer only stores the last page, whereas a Cookie `visited_welcome_page` for example can be stored for multiple requests an so he would even know if the user was on other pages in between

Comment: @byf-ferdy It's up to niko to know what to do, but for the request made using a cookie is overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm mistaken....

If You are sending information of a page to other through form via GET or POST methods,
on the destination page (registration.php) You could simply check if a essential variable is set. e.g.:

```
    if (isset($_POST['user'])){//Check as many variables as You want with AND operator here

##Your code here...
##Here You'll store or manipulate Your properly received values...
##eg:
$user = $_POST['user'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

}
else {

header( 'Location: welcome.php' );//redirecting

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions and cookies are similar in a way that sessions are dependent on cookies. EDIT: valid comment by @swapnesh - if user disables cookies, sessions would still work by sending session ID in URL, not in cookie.

Cookie is a value set in a users user agent (browser). Your PHP script will set this using HTTP headers. Specifically, it will be a `Set-Cookie` header (see [RFC 6265, 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#page-8) for details). In any subsequent reqest made by UA, it will send cookies in headers as well (using `Cookie` header, [RFC 6265, 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#page-13)). The value you set using a cookie will be stored directly in the UA.

Session is some data stored on a serwer associated with the client cookie. This session could be stored in server's memory or in some persistent location (database for instance). If you use sessions, PHP will set the cookie for you, but this time it will not contain the value you set, but some ID. Later, in another request, PHP will read this cookie and use ID to lookup the corresponding data on the server side.

As to your specific question - if user accesses registration.php via some search engine or other (not valid) means, than this request will be either POST, or it will not contains the form fields that are required. So what you can do is simply validate the parameters in registration.php and if those are not present, redirect user to welcome.php. It would work even without cookies/sessions. If this approach is acceptable in your use case, have a look at [http_redirect()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.http-redirect.php). This method will use on example HTTP 301 or HTTP 307 responses.

Comment: Little bit false statement about sessions as `sessions can also be propagated in the URL` so it is not the thing if user disable cookie we can not track users on this basis only

Comment: @swapnesh - true, I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem you're trying to solve is going to be solved with either `Cookies` or `$_SESSION` variables. If you are dead-set on checking if `the user came from a search engine` you want to check what the referrer is, i.e. to see if it's from a search engine. The referrer is basically "what page sent the user to this page."

You can check this by looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and you could do `preg_match()` or something to see if it was from Google, or Bing.

You could also use a different condition `the user has never been to the site before` to redirect them to the welcome page. You would do this by setting setting a cookie on the first visit, send to the welcome page, then use a check on every page visit seeing if the cookie is set to decide whether to show welcome, or just the page. You wouldn't want to use sessions here.

To answer your question about "the server doing less work" the winner would technically be cookies, but you shouldn't make your decision based on this because it's negligible.

Comment: I don't suggest using this at all. HTTP REFERER's can be tampered with as they're client sided as well!

Comment: Okay, but that's the only way he can check if the user came from a search engine. I wouldn't recommend doing that either, but if he really really really is dying to do that, the referrer is the only way. Otherwise, I recommended a different condition to check i.e. `has the cookie been set` i.e. has the visitor visited before.

Answer (score -1):

Cookies are client-sided and they can be tampered by a client easily, but Sessions are server sided and can not be tampered by a client. So I would suggest it would be best if you use a session to check if he is logged in or not.

Comment: should i consider that you know abot session hijacking ?

Comment: Yes. You should. If he secures his user input well and prevents session hijacking through his code then it would be enough. But sessions are definetly safer than cookies

Comment: Why is security what you're discussing here? Do you think it's important to see if a user will "fake" that they haven't been to the site before? I don't think anyone is going to bother... I could see other examples where this might matter i.e. NYT showing content if it came from a search engine, but not here.

Comment: Just because no one is going to bother doesn't mean you can abandon security

Comment: I'm just saying that this isn't a function where the security of the cookie matters... if someone forges the cookie the worst thing that could happen is it emulates the user having already visited the site/not from the search engine... he is only showing a welcome page, not locking down content.

Comment: Which the guy that asked the question clearly doesn't want. He can use a session instead of a cookie which will be safer and which can't be disabled

Comment: @wnajar its about session hijacking see this http://shiflett.org/articles/session-hijacking

Comment: I'm aware of session hijacking.. but I don't think this is especially relevant for a **welcome page**...